# Should I use the sql JOIN keyword for complex joins on multiple tables?

Tags: sql, join

I've got the following request :

```
select * 
    from tbA A, tbB B, tbC C, tbD D
where 
    A.ID=B.ID and B.ID2= C.ID2 and A.ID=D.ID and C.ID3=D.ID3 and B.ID4=D.ID4
and
    A.Foo='Foo'
```

I've heard several times that this join syntax is depreciated, and that I should use the 'JOIN' keyword instead.

How do I do that in such a complicated join (multiple tables joined on multiple columns belonging to different tables)? Do you think this best practice still applies here ?

Comment: The nice thing about using ANSI format is that the join logic is separated from your filtering logic. It makes it very clear to see how the tables are related at a glance.

Comment: Yes, it's deprecated.  And yes you should clean up your sql.

Comment: @Chris : well, it seems the use of this syntax isn't deprecated, while the use of * (to do left joins) is (it's detailed in another answer). re the SQL, I just wrote it as an example

Comment: The more complicated the join the more important it is to use the ANSII standard syntax as it is far less susceptible to accidentally using a cross join.  ALso left and right joins in the old style syntax are deprecated and shouldn't be used even now as they often give back wrong results.

Comment: HLGEM : wrong results? could you elaborate?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's a matter of taste, but I like the JOIN keyword better. It makes the logic clearer and  is more consistent with the LEFT OUTER JOIN syntax that goes with it. Note that you can also use INNER JOIN which is synonymous with JOIN.

The syntax is

```
   a JOIN b
    ON expression relating b to all of the tables before
```

b can be a join itself. For inner joins it doesn't matter, but for outer you can control the order of the joins like this:

```
select * from
   a left join
      d join c
      on d.i = c.i
   on a.k = d.k
```

Here a is left-joined to the inner join between d and c.

Here is your query:

```
select * 
    from tbA A
    join tbB B on A.ID = B.ID
    join tbC C on B.ID2 = C.ID2
    join tbD D on A.ID = D.ID and C.ID3 = D.ID3 and B.ID4 = D.ID4
where 
    A.Foo='Foo'
```

Answer (score 5):

I find join syntax much easier to understand

```
select *
from tbA A
inner join tbB B on a.id = b.id
inner join tbC C on b.id2 = c.id2
inner join tbD D on a.id = d.id and c.id3 = d.id3 and b.id4 = d.id4
where A.Foo='Foo'
```

Now you can clearly see how data are joined together and that it is not a very complicated join altogether.

BTW, the database design in your example strongly smells of lacking normalization. Usually you should have either one table joining to many (a join b on a.bid = b.bid join c on a.cid= c.cid) or a chain (a join b on a.bid = b.bid join c on b.cid = c.cid).

EDIT. Added optional keyword INNER which does not change result, but makes it more clear.

Comment: did you repeat 'a.id = b.id' twice on purpose?

Comment: actually it should be a.id = d.id :) Post corrected.

Btw, this simple problem with naming clearly shows why the design is not correct.

Comment: @wwosik : those names are not the 'real' table names, of course

Comment: I understand :) Possibly I addressed some recollections when I really met someone's table with fields id, id2 and id3...

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tba AS a
    JOIN tbb AS b ON a.id = b.id
    JOIN tbc AS c ON b.id2 = c.id2
    JOIN tbd AS d ON a.id = d.id AND c.id3 = d.id3 AND b.id4 = d.id4
WHERE 
    a.foo = 'Foo'
```

Though I'm having a hard time imagining any need for that. Bare to give an example, or eh more descriptive table names?

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` syntax is more legible (though I personally prefer `WHERE` syntax in simple cases), and, which is more important, can handle `INNER` and `OUTER` joins in more clear way.

`WHERE` is not deprecated and will probably never be.

It's deprecated only in a sense that different `OUTER JOIN` workarounds (like `(*)` and `(+)`) are deprecated.

There is nothing you cannot do with `JOIN` that you can do with `WHERE`, but not vise versa.

Comment: Indeed. Now I remember seeing this message when using * in a join